# How to align two circles so they will be in one plane?

Tags: modeling, transforms

[image]How to align two green circles shown in pic so they will be in one plane. Model is not oriented perpendicular to any other axis so scale to y,z, or x then 0 do not work. I can rotate the whole model to match x-axis but it takes time. I am sure there is a simpler way.

Comment: Change your global axis to normal, change snap settings to vertices activate it. Select the circle green press G then Z and snap to the vertices you want https://ibb.co/cb13xrP

Comment: Thank you. It rly works :)